# An Inequality related to the Trace Norm

Tags: quantum-operation, information-theory, trace-norm

Let $\rho, \sigma$ be two states of a qubit, and let $U$ be the $CX_{12}$-gate (control on 1st qubit, target on 2nd qubit). 
Prove that, for an arbitrary CPTP Map $\mathcal{E}$,
$$
||\mathcal{E}(\rho - \sigma)||_1 \leq ||\mathcal{E}\otimes\mathcal{I}\left(U\left\{(\rho - \sigma)\otimes |0\rangle\langle 0|\right\}U^{\dagger}\right)||_1
$$

where, $||A||_1 = \rm{Tr}(|A|) = \rm{Tr}(\sqrt{A^{\dagger}A})$ is the Trace-Norm of $A$.

*Generalization*: 
What conditions does $U$ need to satisfy in general so that this inequality holds for arbitrary states $\rho, \sigma$ and arbitrary CPTP Maps $\mathcal{E}$ ?